# Create a sub-row/child row in datagrid from a list of objects in my parent object C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

So let's say for this example I have an object of type car right.
The car class is as follows:

```
class Car
{
    public string Make { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public List<Wheel> Wheels { get; set; }
}
```

and the Wheel class is as follows:

```
class Wheel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Size { get; set; }
    public string Shape { get; set; }
    public string Brand{ get; set; }
}
```

so basically what I want is for the `List<Wheel> wheels` to display in a sub row/child row

See screenshot below:

[image: What I want]

I am working in C# WPF

Comment: What have you tried so far? Issues sounds very google-able.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is how you can display your data in nested grid way

```
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Cars}" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
              RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Visible"
              CanUserAddRows="False" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Make" Binding="{Binding Make}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Model" Binding="{Binding Model}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Wheels}" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CanUserAddRows="False">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding Path=ID}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Size" Binding="{Binding Path=Size}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Shape" Binding="{Binding Path=Shape}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Brand" Binding="{Binding Path=Brand}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
    </DataGrid>
```

[image]

Comment: Appreciate the help!